# Typescript: How to remove undefined from return type when default value is provided

Tags: typescript

```js
class MyStore {
    data: Record<string, string> = {};
    getKey(key: string, defaultValue?: string): string | undefined {
        return this.data[key] ?? defaultValue;
    }
}

const store = new MyStore();

const value1 = store.getKey("test");
const value2 = store.getKey("test", "def");
```

1. Now `value1` has type of `string | undefined`. It is right, no problem there.
2. But `value2` has also same type of `value1`. How to update signature of `getKey()` so that when default value is provided, there will be no `undefined`. Like `value2` should be of type `string` only.

Comment: Why is the method contracted to return `string` if `defaultValue` is of any type `T` (not even constrained here)? Is this intended? In current form (`getKey(...)`) without `T` introduced anywhere it's not even a valid ts.

Comment: I have updated the code. Made an error while modifying the code for question snippet.

Comment: Great, the answer that suggests overloads now should fit you perfectly.

Comment: Yep. My answer changed to reflect the edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way (which also plays nicely with intellisense) is with function overloads:

```
class MyStore {
  data: Record<string, string> = {};
  getKey(key: string): string | undefined // callable signature
  getKey(key: string, defaultValue: string): string // callable signature
  getKey(key: string, defaultValue?: string): 
      string | undefined { //implementation signature
    return this.data[key] ?? defaultValue;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlALgewE4FNoG8BQ00AJmMmAFzQBKmwGRAPBMugJYB2A5gDTTNtcAfNAC8uAL4BuAtE6ZkAaUzwAFAGtllfh04BKLSx3QAPtACu7IpgBmHTERlzFy9Zr6GuvK9bBmQyADUwEDNMAwE9cJ1HeSVVDXgoz2IbX38gkMwAfiTI9wiTc0sbOyJcGUIsZDN0dmhkAAtWCAA6EjIAbQSAXWgsrJSfP0Dg0OlCcTxJvDp2ZncMbDF2TAB3OCQ0LBVdaRnUOeRoADdRzABGUQWsFqc4lQAiZExmB928AHoPwkIAPSz9ocTmcAExXZiLW6xFxPF7IB68B7eN7SL4-aD-IA)

You could also work this out with generics and conditional types for a considerably less readable solution:

```
class MyStore {
  data: Record<string, string> = {};
  getKey<T extends string | undefined>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): 
      T extends string ? string : string | undefined {
    return this.data[key] ?? defaultValue;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlALgewE4FNoG8BQ00AJmMmAFzQBKmwGRAPBMugJYB2A5gDTTNtcAfNAC8uAL4BuAtE6ZkAaUzwGAFWiYAHskzsiMfh07QAPtACuezADMOmIoIAUAa2WVDXXkRthzIZABqYCDmmAD8lKoAlJEa2rr6fCxG0GFJAsbuyVymFla27Pa4MoRYyObo7NDIABasEAB0JGQA2q7wALqpad7Wvv5BIZjShOJ4Y3h07MxJGNhihQDucEhoWI5R0pOo08jQAG7BoQCMorNYDXKKyo4ARDrMt5t4APQvhIQAemHbuwdHmAATGdmHNLvIlPA7g9kLdeLdek9pG8PtBvkA)

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic should work but your return value should not contain string anyway. Since, your `Record`s values are of type `any`.

```
getKey<T = undefined>(key: string, defaultValue?: T): string | T {
        return this.data[key] ?? defaultValue;
}
```

If you are planning on using only strings for the values. I suggest updating the type of the record.

```
data: Record<string, string> = {};
```

Comment: I have updated the code. Made an error while modifying the code for question snippet.